# Links give invalid response code from code but valid response code from browser

Tags: java, http-response-codes, external-links

I'm validating links by trying to hit them and getting the response codes(in Java). But I get invalid response codes(403 or 404) from code but from browser, I get 200 status code when I inspect the network activity. Here's my code that gets the response code. [I do basic validations on urls beforehand, like making it lowercase, etc.]

```
static int getResponseCode(String link) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(link);
    HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    return http.getResponseCode();
}
```

For link like http://science.sciencemag.org/content/220/4599/868, I am getting 403 status when I run this code. But on browser(chrome), I am getting 200 status. Also, if I use the below curl command, I am getting 200 status code.

```
curl -Is http://science.sciencemag.org/content/220/4599/868
```

Comment: That website probably doesn't like bots, and checks whether incoming requests are made by known browsers. That may sound stupid, but it's a rather common attitude.

Comment: Do check all request headers and response headers in your browser - then see what's different in your code.  Also make sure to read the body of the response after you get 403 or 404 - it may have additional information.

Comment: Your code is correct, but seems something is wrong with the URL you are trying to test. I am afraid somehow the HttURLConnection class is not able to get the right url address

Comment: @kumesana any way to overcome that? also, if I use curl, I am getting correct status code.

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you used to make the request?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to overcome that is to:

- check what are the HTTP headers sent by your program (for instance, by sending queries to http://scooterlabs.com/echo and check the response)
- check what are the HTTP headers sent by your browser (for instance, by visiting https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending )
- spot the differences
- change your program to send the same headers as your browser (the ones that work)

I made this analysis for you, and it turns out this website requires an `Accept` header that resemble the Accept headers of an existing browser. By default Java sends something valid, but not resembling that.

You just need to change your program as so:

```
static int getResponseCode(String link) throws IOException {
  URL url = new URL(link);
  HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
  return http.getResponseCode();
}
```

(Or any other value that an actual browser uses)